# Orden de columnas en JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatable, jquery-ui

Tengo una duda (quizá básica, no lo sé) con el orden de las columnas de `DataTable`. La cosa es que necesito desactivar la opción "**ordering**" en las últimas 4 columnas de mi `DataTable` ¿Es eso posible?

De ante mano, Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿qué has intentado? Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask] y hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que tengas 8 columnas en total, lo harias asi:

```
$('#miTabla').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    {
        orderable: false,
        targets: [4,5,6,7]
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: Gracias!!! era justo eso !